# Visual Prolog 5.2 Реализация case\switch на prolog.

Tags: prolog, visual-prolog

Доброго времени суток. 
Стоит такая задача - необходимо считать значение из edit и если это например 1 , то выполнить одни действия,если 2,то другие. 
В любом другом ЯП воспользовался бы **case** или **switch** , но, как мне известно , в прологе таких нет. 
Подскажите, как можно реализовать данную задачу?

Comment: если не ошибаюсь в прологе это устанавливается фактами или утверждениями.

Comment: Да,я читал,что можно делать правила. Но Так и не смог найти дельной реализации.

Comment: это же основа языка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давай более подробное описание задачи - есть много вариантов решений.

```
switch (var) {
  case 1:
    write('hello');
    break;
  case 2:
    write('world');
    break;
  default: // not any case it switch
    write('not hello world');
}
```

На прологе можно записать **например** так:

```
switch(1):-
  write('hello'), !.
switch(2):-
  write('world'), !.
switch(_AnyCase):-
  write('not hello world').
```

Но есть и другие варианты. Посмотри по теме [реализации ветвления на Prolog](http://pro-prof.com/forums/topic/if-then-else-prolog).